# Compare 2 rows in Excel and Add total

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am currently working on a spreadsheet where in 1 row I have a numberical value representative of hours, the second row (and every row after that) contains either a Yes/No word.

[image]

The question is if I am able to in a third box to add the total values from the row which has numerical values based on whether the second row says Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `=SUMIF(condition_interval, condition, sum_interval)` function.

I'm using a pt-br version, so my `=SOMASE` is equal to `=SUMIF`.

Formula: `=SUMIF(B4:H4, "Yes", B3:H3)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMIF` with three arguments: `=SUMIF(A2:F2;"YES";A1:F1)`. If the values in A2:F2 equal "YES", the corresponding values are A1:F1 added.